# Error ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type from PyZeroMQ server

Tags: python, c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

Having a problem trying to parse a Json object returned from my Python server.
The error I am getting is
"ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type."

The puzzling thing is if I take **the exact string** returned from the server and hard code it before passing it to the parsing method Player.CreateFromJSON it works!

These are the 3 relevant lines in the Python server

```
 x = '{"playerId":8484239823,"playerLoc":"Powai","playerNick":"Random Nick"}'
 y = json.dumps(x)
 socket.send_string(y)
```

This is the JSON string returned.

```
"{\"playerId\":8484239823,\"playerLoc\":\"Powai\",\"playerNick\":\"Random Nick\"}"
```

This is my Player object

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public string playerId;
    public string playerLoc;
    public string playerNick;

    public static Player CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<Player>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Am using Unity's native JsonUtility FromJson method as can be seen from above and I simply call

```
Player playerInfo = Player.CreateFromJSON(jsonStringFromServer);
```

to populate the Player object

Have spent countless hours googling and trying to find similar issues. Any feedback or troubleshooting steps welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your Python code; namely, `x` is already a JSON string; you don't need to call `json.dumps(x)`, you can send it direct using `socket.send_string(x)` instead.

In fact, `y = json.dumps(x)` returns *a JSON-encoded JSON string!*:

```
'"{\\"playerId\\":8484239823,\\"playerLoc\\":\\"Powai\\",\\"playerNick\\":\\"Random Nick\\"}"'
```

which cannot be decoded into a `Player` object - because it's a `string`! Remove that line in your Python code, and just `socket.send_string(x)` directly.

Comment: (Or send an actual object, not string, to dumps..)